# Email in VBA: Adding links

Tags: html, vba, excel, hyperlink

For some reason, this is only putting the path up to the specified NCR number (i.e. R:\Quality\NCR's[the NCR number here] and that's it). I cannot figure out why it's not pulling the rest of the information (the PN and the .xlsm) into the link. Please help!

```
Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
Dim PN As String
Dim NCR As String
Dim my_hyperlink As String



PN = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Value
NCR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I4").Value

my_hyperlink = "R:\Quality\NCR's\" & NCR & " " & PN & ".xlsm"

On Error GoTo debugs
Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
With Mail_Single
.Subject = "NCR: Part Failed Appearance"
.To = "me@workemail.com"
.cc = "me@workemail.com"
.HTMLBody = PN & " has failed for appearance issues and requires a marketing disposition. This part has been cleared by engineering. Please see NCR number " & NCR & " in NCR Log for more details. See the Report <a href=" & my_hyperlink & ">Here</a>"
.send
End With
```

Comment: You can't start with an ampersand.

Comment: remove the first `&` from your string. It should be `Email_Body = PN & " has failed for appearance issues and requires a   marketing disposition. This part has been cleared by engineering. Please see NCR number " & NCR & "in NCR Log for more details."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have indicated, the line:

```
Email_Body = & PN & " has failed for appearance issues and requires a   marketing disposition. This part has been cleared by engineering. Please see NCR number " & NCR & "in NCR Log for more details."
```

Should be changed to:

```
Email_Body = PN & " has failed for appearance issues and requires a   marketing disposition. This part has been cleared by engineering. Please see NCR number " & NCR & "in NCR Log for more details."
```

As you do not need an ampersand at the start.

In terms of the hyperlink, you could do the following:

```
dim my_hyperlink as string
my_hyperlink = "R:\Quality\" & NCR & "'s\" & NCR & " " & PN & ".xlsm"
```

In order to add this into the email you should use `.HTMLBody` and so replace the lines you have with these (I've added the hyperlink at the end of your sentence):

```
Email_Body = PN & " has failed for appearance issues and requires a   marketing disposition. This part has been cleared by engineering. Please see NCR number " & NCR & "in NCR Log for more details. The hyperlink is <a href=" & my_hyperlink & ">click here</a>"

With Mail_Single
.Subject = Email_Subject
.To = Email_Send_To
.cc = Email_Cc
.BCC = Email_Bcc
.HTMLBody = Email_Body
.send
End With
```

For efficiency and readability, you could change your code to:

```
Sub emailmarketing()

Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
Dim PN As String
Dim NCR As String

PN = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Value
NCR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I4").Value

On Error GoTo debugs
Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
With Mail_Single
.Subject = "Non-Conformance Report: Part Failed Appearance"
.To = "me@workemail.com"
.cc = "me@workemail.com"
.HTMLBody = PN & " has failed for appearance issues and requires a   marketing disposition. This part has been cleared by engineering. Please see NCR number " & NCR & "in NCR Log for more details. The hyperlink is <a href=" & my_hyperlink & ">click here</a>"
.send
End With
debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Let me know if this works :)

Comment: You may or may not have just made me cry in relief. Thank you so so so much.

Comment: No problem, if it works please accept it as the answer, otherwise let me know :)

Comment: Unfortunately the link isn't quite working all the way. I've edited my post so you can see where I'm at now. Any idea as to why it's not taking the whole thing?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the data that would be stored in NCR and PN?

Comment: NCR will always be a 5 digit number and PN will be a number from 4 digits to over 10, depending

Comment: @ladymrt have you got an example of the link? E.g. R:\Quality\12345's\12345 123456.xlsm

Comment: R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR 12345 123456.xlsm

Comment: the first two instances of the letters "NCR" need to be as is. The folder these forms are in is literally called "NCR's". The naming convention for these files is "NCR" [the NCR #] [the part number].xlsm

Comment: Ok, well if that's the case I think the line should be `my_hyperlink = "R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR" & " " & NCR & " " & PN & ".xlsm"`

Comment: Still only pulling up to the first end-quotes (R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR) wondering why the & statements aren't getting included? Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Try double quoting, so `my_hyperlink = ""R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR"" & "" "" & NCR & "" "" & PN & "".xlsm""`

Comment: reds it out and gives me a syntax error with the whole line highlighted.

Comment: .HTMLBody = PN & " has failed for appearance issues and requires a marketing disposition. This part has been cleared by engineering. Please see NCR number " & NCR & " in NCR Log for more details.  <a href=""" & my_hyperlink & """>NCR " & NCR & "</a>"

Comment: Triple quoting the link in the actual body of the email actually fixed it. Thank you again times a million for all of your help, I would not have been able to do this without ya!

Comment: No problem, the syntax is sometimes quite odd! Thanks for accepting the answer, could you also vote it up please.

Comment: I'm too new for my votes to count visibly, but sure thing!

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation operator & (or +) requires an operand on each side.

```
Email_Body = & PN & " has failed for ap
```

Should be

```
Email_Body = PN & " has failed for ap
```